# How to post Subject Matter Expert to Azure DevOps via Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am pushing a list of requirements to Azure DevOps, which include title, description, tags and priority. I would also like to add subject matter experts, but didn't find any information on the syntax.

So far I have tried posting it using the following options:

```
{"op": "add","path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.SubjectMatterExpert","from": null,"value": "test"}

{"op": "add","path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.SubjectMatterExperts","from": null,"value": "test"}

{"op": "add","path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.SubjectMatterExpert1","from": null,"value": "test"}

{"op": "add","path": "/fields/System.SubjectMatterExpert","from": null,"value": "test"}

{"op": "add","path": "/fields/System.SubjectMatterExperts","from": null,"value": "test"}

{"op": "add","path": "/fields/System.SubjectMatterExpert1","from": null,"value": "test"}
```

They all return the same error:

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF51535: Cannot find field Microsoft.VSTS.Common.SubjectMatterExpert.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.Metadata.WorkItemTrackingFieldDefinitionNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server","typeKey":"WorkItemTrackingFieldDefinitionNotFoundException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3200}
```

Comment: May I know how's the status of this before weekend? Does below request body format is work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use below format:

```
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.SubjectMatterExpert1",
    "from": null,
    "value": "{account here}"
  }
```

**Result:**

[image]